# How to unlock the mirror without the EOS Utility in Canon T3i

Tags: canon, mirror, eos-utility

I often use EOS Utility 2 for several compositions in studio, and I block the mirror from the app. But when I disconnect the cam, the option is still on but I can't figure how to deactivate it from the camera without a connection to the utility.

Comment: It's not clear at all what you are asking? Are you saying mirror lockup remains enabled when you disconnect the camera?

Comment: Have you try power off then power on the camera?

Comment: @RomeoNinov Power cycling will not change the mirror lockup setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's at Menu → Settings (yellow wrench) tab 3 → Custom Settings → C.Fn-8 Mirror Lockup → 0: Disable.

It's covered on pages 250 and 255 of the [*EOS Rebel T3i/EOS 600D Instruction Manual*](https://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/0/0300004720/02/eosrt3i-eos600d-im2-c-en.pdf)

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael!! I wont never found with help. And thanks a lot for the Instruction Manual link!!!! have a really nice great day!!!!